# I'm trying to use cat command and the bteq command in LX shell script - it is not recognized

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I'm trying to use cat command and the bteq command in LX shell script - it is not recognized. It perfectly works in Solaris.

[image: Here is the png image for the reference]

Can anyone solve this?

Comment: This is barely readable – [please don't post images of text](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/85695). Instead, paste the text directly into your question and use the [formatting tools](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting).

Comment: What is `cat > filename` supposed to do?